# Print result horizontally

Tags: layout, printing, jasper-reports

I think I am trying something different than most other posters asking about horizontal printing .. at least I think so!

I have a label that is currently printing two copies of each result - one on each half of the detail band.   Basically they just took the fields and put an identical set next to each other in order to get two labels for each row returned.    Now we only need one and I cannot get it to use the second column for the next label - best I can do is get the second one to be blank, except when there is more than one result in one field...then instead of printing it below the other one it prints just that field in the second column.

I copied some of what I assumed are the relevant settings from the jasperreports HorizontalReport.jrxml sample, including

```
Columns = 2, Print Order = Horizontal.  Column Space = 5, Column Width=289
```

I even put a frame around my fields but that didn't help.

Here is the jrxml I am using. (I changed a few field names and removed the params and query)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="d_allergy_cautions_rpt.srd" language="groovy" columnCount="2" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="800" columnWidth="289" columnSpacing="5" leftMargin="14" rightMargin="14" topMargin="36" bottomMargin="36" uuid="3d9bd29d-ecad-4bdd-90f1-a1e5737a4290">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<field name="one" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[one_COLUMN_1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="two" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[two_COLUMN_2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="three" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[three_COLUMN_3]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="diet_caution" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[diet_caution_COLUMN_6]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="calories" class="java.lang.Long">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[calories_COLUMN_7]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="more_cautions_flg" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[more_cautions_flg_COLUMN_14]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<variable name="CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<group name="1">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{one}.toString()]]></groupExpression>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="1"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<pageHeader>
    <band/>
</pageHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="48" splitType="Prevent">
        <textField pattern="[general]" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="2" y="8" width="28" height="22" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" printWhenGroupChanges="1" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d530fc96-dc89-4280-a0e8-be4d4efdfa15"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="16" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(($F{more_cautions_flg}.equals("Y")) ? "*" : "")]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="[general]" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="31" y="36" width="98" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" printWhenGroupChanges="1" forecolor="#000000" uuid="942c6421-1aa5-4cfb-bd55-ca9d3a7793f2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{calories}==null?  "" : $F{calories} + " Calorie"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="[general]" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="29" y="18" width="202" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" printWhenGroupChanges="1" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="69540580-ba24-41d8-aed0-d839e16b6bb9">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[((($F{diet_caution}.equals("")) || ($F{diet_caution}.equals("ADA DIET DO NOT SHOW"))) ? 0 : 1) == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{diet_caution}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="[general]" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="9" y="0" width="203" height="12" printWhenGroupChanges="1" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="961ad14c-d77c-40c8-a218-473f3e2a3212"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{two}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="[general]" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="234" y="0" width="39" height="12" printWhenGroupChanges="1" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="6857d450-2d00-48f0-9bd7-73ed6de3d03a"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{three}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="12">
        <textField pattern="[general]" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="392" y="2" width="184" height="10" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f5346fdd-7447-470c-883a-5153303dbb21"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Report for " + new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(TODAY())]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="204" y="0" width="164" height="12" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="8209f151-af1b-473e-977d-8418ae00ac34"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ * = Additional Data ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="3" y="2" width="127" height="10" forecolor="#808080" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="7f33d259-417c-42b3-9a3c-dc50d874d678"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[file location]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Where am I going wrong here?

EDIT:  Current output is like this:

```
Doe, John A          2A21      Doe, John A      2A21
  High Protein Diet            High Protein Diet
__________________________     ______________________
Smith, Steve M        3B32     Smith, Steve M   3B32  
  Halal Diet                      Halal Diet
  ADA Diet 2400 Cal               ADA Diet  2400 Cal
```

I would like for it to look like this:

```
Doe, John A          2A21      Smith, Steve M     3B32
  High Protein Diet              Halal Diet
                                 ADA Diet 2400 Cal
__________________________     __________________________
```

It seems to me that - everything else being equal - isPrintRepeatedValues should be false....There should only be one of each of several types of diet for each person.

When I made it two columns and PrintOrder = Horizontal it would do something like this if there were more than one diet entry:

```
Smith, Steve M       3B32
   Halal Diet                          ADA Diet - 2400 Cal
_____________________________           ____________________________
```

It did not print the next entry but continued the existing one in the second column.  Otherwise the second column is blank.

I hope this makes the question clearer.   I don't know how to make the code more verifiable without putting the actual query in ... which no one can run anyway.   I presumed the output of the query is evident based on the textfields in the detail band.  I removed some of the fields which were not even being used and it still runs the same.

Comment: Its not an example we can run, for us to understand you need to create a [mcve] a simple jrxml with a simple datasource (example empty), maybe isPrintRepeatedValues="false" is not what you need (ifi you have same data in next record il will not print)

Comment: Please try to make you question more clear (current output, expected output) etc, [edit] it